# How to invoke RunInstances action on ec2.amazonaws.com using shell script?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Every time I am getting the error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date +%FT%TZ | sed 's/:/%3A/g')
echo "$dt"

q="GET
elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=652387uyt56182&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=$dt&Version=2009-03-31"
 sig=$(echo -n "$q" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac q65272/ui5878/t62989231232 - binary| openssl enc -base64)

echo "the signature without url encoding is $sig"


curl --get --url  "https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StartInstances&AWSAccessKeyId=ty76476587yt4756&InstanceId.1=t-76wergf&MaxCount=1&MinCount=1&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=$dt&Signature=$sig&Version=2012-07-20"
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code? I have altered my secret credentials for confidentiality.
Thanks.

Comment: You've got different action parameters in the string to sign & actual request. You may want to consider using the aws cli

Comment: @frederick -Is there any mistake in my shell script??Can you suggest me a link or site where I can get the optimal result..

Comment: Like I said, the action parameter in the string you are signing doesn't not match the request you are making. You also need to include the other parameters (InstanceId etc.) in the string to sign